# New Pandas Series longer than original dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file, append

So I have a data set with user, date, and post columns. I'm trying to generate a column of the calories that foods contain in the post column for each user. This dataset has a length of 21, and the code below finds the food words, get their calorie value, append it to that user's respective calorie list, and append that list to the new column. The new generated column, however, somehow has a length of 25:

```
Current data: 21 
New column:  25
```

Does anybody know why this occurs? Here is the code below and samples of what the original dataset and the new column look like:

```
while len(col) < len(data['post']):
    for post, api_id, api_key in zip(data['post'], ids_keys.keys(), ids_keys.values()): # cycles through text data & api keys

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'x-app-id': api_id,
            'x-app-key': api_key,
            'x-remote-user-id': '0'
        }

        calories = []
        print('Current data:', len(data['post']), '\n New column: ', len(col)) # prints length of post vs new cal column
        for word in eval(post):
            if word not in food:
                continue
            else:
                print('Detected Word: ', word)
                query = {'query': '{}'.format(word)}
                try:
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=query)
                except KeyError as ke:
                    print(ke, 'Out of calls, next key...')
                    ids_keys.pop(api_id) # drop current api id & key from dict if out of calls
                    print('API keys left:', len(ids_keys))
                finally:
                    stats = response.json()
                    print('Food Stats: \n', stats)
                    print('Calories in food: ', stats['foods'][0]['nf_calories'])
                    calories.append(stats['foods'][0]['nf_calories'])
                    print('Current Key', api_id, ':', api_key)
        col.append(calories)
    if len(col) == len(data['post']):
        break
```

I attempted to use the while loop to only append up to the length of the dataset, but to no avail.

Original Data Set:

```
pd.DataFrame({'user':['avskk', 'janejellyn', 'firlena227','...'],
 'date': ['October 22', 'October 22', 'October 22','...'],
 'post': [['autumn', 'fully', 'arrived', 'cooking', 'breakfast', 'toaster','...'],
        ['breakfast', 'chinese', 'sticky', 'rice', 'tempeh', 'sausage', 'cucumber', 'salad', 'lunch', 'going', 'lunch', 'coworkers', 'probably', 'black', 'bean', 'burger'],
        ['potato', 'bean', 'inspiring', 'food', 'day', 'today', '...']]
})
```

New Column:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Calories': [[22,33,45,32,2,5,7,9,76],
                          [43,78,54,97,32,56,97],
                          [23,55,32,22,7,99,66,98,54,35,33]]
             })
```

Comment: please do not post your data as pictures.

Comment: @d_kennetz How should I post it then?

Comment: type a small representative example set of your data that can reproduce the problem you are facing. We should be able to take the code you post, run it, and see the issue you are facing. Right now, someone would have to click on that small picture and copy by typing all of those columns. Instead, you should do that leg work for the people solving your issue.